# Is it possible for two strong lenses to cancel each other effects?

Tags: visible-light, lenses, vision

Is it possible for a lens system for 2 strong lenses to cancel each other, so it looks almost the same as a common glass, while at the same time making an object in between them appear big and distant?
Could it be done with flat fresnel lenses?
EDIT: Ok, it's ok to have more lenses, what wouldn't serve me is them to be too far or for the system to be too big

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to build a "window" that you can place a small object inside and have it magnified to appear as part of the scene outside?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's pretty much like it! Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible. For examppe researchers at Rochester [used this](http://www.rochester.edu/newscenter/watch-rochester-cloak-uses-ordinary-lenses-to-hide-objects-across-continuous-range-of-angles-70592/) to effectively cloak a small space when viewed from the right angles, since the lenses do bend the light passing between them thus occupying a cone shape instead of the entire cylinder. They use four lenses to obtain this. The way I think they do this is by placing two pairs of lenses at each others focal points, which should not magnify, but would invert the image, therefore you require two sets of these (four lenses in total) to invert it twice and get back to normal.

The researchers used four lenses, probably to increase the [volume which would be cloaked](http://isites.harvard.edu/icb/icb.do?keyword=k16940&panel=icb.pagecontent1572465%3Ar%241%3Fname%3Dindepth.html&pageid=icb.page93268&pageContentId=icb.pagecontent221625&view=view.do&viewParam_name=indepth.html):

[image]

However you can get away with just using three lenses if you just want to cancel the effects. For example you could use the following configuration:

[image]

where the three vertical black lines represent (thin) lenses, with focal points $F_1$, $F_2$ and $F_3$ from left to right, with in this case $F_1=2F_2=F_3$, such that all three lenses can have the same size.

I do not think that this can be simplified any further, or you would have to allow to use a concave and convex lens and glue them together, such that you obtain an effective optic with no effect.

Comment: Really you are saying "no; you need four lenses". But it is an awesome answer for the link to the Rochester Cloaking Device

Comment: @Floris You are correct, I somehow thought I remembered they used only two lenses, with two lenses, with their focal points in the same place the image would be mirrored.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is no. Two lenses in series is the basic idea behind the [telescope](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/teles.html) and the problem with this is that the image is always inverted. So you could make a window with two Fresnel lenses which would be (sort of) undistorted for far objects, but the outside world would be upside-down. There's also the matter of various distortions and aberrations, but I think the inversion problem makes them moot.